# Change class on click using knockout.js css binding

Tags: javascript, knockout-3.0

In the following div, the 'active' class is NOT currently visible(per design).  If I manually change the isActive value to 'true', the 'active' class is visible in the div.

```
<div class="content-nav-bar"data-bind="css: {'active' : 'isActive()' === false}">
<button type="button" data-bind="chgCSS>Submit</button>
```

How do I change the state of isActive when I click the button using knockout.js?

Remove hard-coded value:

```
<div class="content-nav-bar"data-bind="css: {'active' : 'isActive()'}">
```

In js file have function:

```
chgCSS = function(){
    isActive: ko.observable(true)
};
```

I thank you in advance for helping me (newcomer to coding)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to bind `isActive` to `this`, i.e., the viewModel. Only then it will be available to use in the HTML.
2. Second, once you define an observable, you can update its value by simply using brackets since an observable is a function. E.g. :

   ```
   this.isActive = ko.observable(false); //initialising the variable and setting the initial value to false
   this.isActive(true); //Updating the value to true
   var currentValue = this.isActive(); // calling the observable with empty brackets fetches the current value
   ```
3. The correct syntax for binding a function to a button is `data-bind = 'click: functionName'`

Here's the working fiddle with your code (Click 'Run Code Snippet'):

```js
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.isActive = ko.observable(false);
  
  self.chgCSS = function(){
    self.isActive(!self.isActive()); //to switch between true and false
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="content-nav-bar"data-bind="css: {'active' : isActive()}">
hello
</div>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: chgCSS">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and coding btw :)